# Basic try: help python

Tags: python, try-catch

I have this function where the user is supposed to give a number. I am having a little issue with my try function. If I enter a string like "abc", it will first tell me to give an integer. So when I write "123" next time, it won't work. This is what I receive then:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'limit' referenced before assignment
```

My code:

```
def limitchooser()
     try:
          limit = int(input("Enter your limit: "))
     except ValueError:
          print("Please enter an integer!")
          limitchooser()
     return limit
```

Comment: Performing input validation using recursion is dangerous, because the program will crash with `maximum recursion depth exceeded` if the user enters invalid data too many times in a row. [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring the return value of a recursive call, so in the function where there was a `ValueError` exception, `limit` is *never set*.

You want to assign the returned value from recursive calls:

```
def limitchooser()
     try:
          limit = int(input("Enter your limit: "))
     except ValueError:
          print("Please enter an integer!")
          limit = limitchooser()
     return limit
```

Better still, *don't use recursion*. Any sufficiently determined user will break your recursion limit instead. Use a loop here:

```
def limitchooser()
     while True:
         try:
              return int(input("Enter your limit: "))
         except ValueError:
              print("Please enter an integer!")
```

The `while True:` creates an infinite loop, but the `return` will exit the function breaking the loop (provided an integer was entered).